# Add event listener to JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm getting back an array of JavaScript objects from a database. I'm looping through that array and creating objects to be displayed on the screen. I'm trying to use `.addEventListener()` to each object but I just realized that `addEventListener()` only works for DOM objects.

How could I add an event listener to each JavaScript object?

Here is my code:

```
    var objects = JSON.parse(data.responseText);
    var i;
    var objectLn = objects.length;

    for (i = 0; i < objectLn; i++) {

        //Puts each object into a variable
        var eachObject = objects[i];

        //Establishes pin position
        var pinPos = {
            lat: parseFloat(eachObject.lat),
            lng: parseFloat(eachObject.lng)
        };

        //Creates new icon for pin
        var icon = {
            url: "path/to/img",
            scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(60, 60),
            origin: null,
            anchor: null
        };

        //Creates a new pin from pulled information
        var pin = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: pinPos,
            map: map,
            icon: icon
        });

        //Alerts each object on click
        pin.addListener('click', function() {
            alert(JSON.stringify(eachObject));
            map.panTo(pinPos);
            map.setCenter(pinPos);
        });
    }
```

`addListener` is adding a 'click' listener to each pin that is dropped, so that's good. The problem is that it's supposed to alert each object, but it's only alerting the last object I retrieve from the database on every pin I click.

Comment: How are you displaying these objects on screen if not using the DOM?

Comment: what kind of events are you hoping to listen for?

Comment: @Pamblam I was looking to add 'click' events to each one

Comment: you can't click on an object. so it doesn't make much sense to add a click event to one.

Comment: if you want click events then that means that you muct be creating dom objects for each one. use the dom objects.

Comment: i mean you cant click anything unless you draw it to the page, right?

Comment: @Pamblam it's drawn on the page, but they are pins on a map. I used .addListener() and that worked, but I wanted to alert information about each pin but it only alerts information about the last object in the array

Comment: that would have been good info to put in the question. show what you've got so far and maybe we can help you work out the issues.

Comment: Wien you add a listener to the Pins, you  have to create the logic what data to Show. Für ex. Save objects Array index in your marker Pin and than on event pick the correct item from your array

Comment: @Pamblam updated! Sorry about that!

Comment: @KevinB Sorry, I updated my post with code! Sorry about that

Comment: eachObject is being overridden on each iteration, for loops don't have their own scope (unless using es2015 let and const) the array forEach method would be more suitable than a for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try doing your loopage like so..

```
for (i = 0; i < objectLn; i++) {
    (function(eachObject){
        // copy the loop contents here. eachObject is already defined.
    })(objects[i]);
}
```